# The argument type 'Iterable<CloudNote>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<CloudNote>'

Tags: flutter

Hello guys I need help in this error I tried a lot but nothing is working I am trying to make some notes but because of this error nots are not showing on home screen.

```
body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: _notesService.allNotes(ownerUserId: userId),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
        case ConnectionState.waiting:
        case ConnectionState.active:
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            final allNotes = snapshot.data as Iterable<CloudNote>;
            return NotesListView(
              notes: allNotes,
              onDeleteNote: (note) async {
                await _notesService.deleteNote(documentId: note.documentId);
              },
              onTap: (note) {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                  createOrUpdateNoteRoute,
                  arguments: note,
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        default:
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
      }
    },
  ),
```

Please help me in this I will be very thank full.

Comment: `notes: allNotes.toList()`, or remove the `as Iterable<CloudNote>`

Answer (score 0):

This error happens whenever you try to pass an `Iterable<T>` to something that expects a `List<T>`. Based on your code, there are two possible cases:

1. Try removing the `as Iterable<CloudNote>` (and perhaps changing to a `List<CloudNote>` assuming it is one). Ideally, your StreamBuilder should be typed, like `StreamBuilder<List<CloudNote>>`.
2. Change `notes: allNotes,` to `notes: allNotes.toList(),`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
notes: allNotes
```

to

```
notes: allNotes.toList()
```